# Problem with Scrolling in WinForm C# in Panel and button emulation swipe

Tags: c#, winforms, smooth-scrolling

I have a problem with scrolling in WinForm C# in Panel AutoScroll with Dynamic created buttons.

On Form1.cs Created a Panel1 with Manual Designed Buttons (6 or 7) and set `autoscroll= true`.  You can `click.down` and scroll anywhere in panel1 as it scrolls the way it should. But if I create it dynamic buttons (as coded) it does not work. I  `click.down` on buttons and i can not scroll. I'm able to scroll if I click outside buttons ie. in the Panel1 and it works. I need to click anywhere!

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace ScrollTouch
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                new TouchScroll(panel1);
            }
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.Text = i.ToString();      
                    b.Size = new Size(100, 90);
                    b.Location =  new Point(i*140, 0);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(b);
                }
    
            }
        }
    }
```

This is just a class TouchScroll.c (class)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ScrollTouch
{

    public class TouchScroll
    {

        private Point mouseDownPoint;
        private Panel parentPanel;

        public TouchScroll(Panel panel)
        {
            parentPanel = panel;
            AssignEvent(panel);

        }

        private void AssignEvent(Control control)
        {
            control.MouseDown += MouseDown;
            control.MouseMove += MouseMove;
            foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
            {
                AssignEvent(child);
            }
        }

        private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
                return;

            Point pointDifference = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - mouseDownPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y + mouseDownPoint.Y);
            if ((mouseDownPoint.X == Cursor.Position.X) && (mouseDownPoint.Y == Cursor.Position.Y))
                return;

            Point currAutos = parentPanel.AutoScrollPosition;
            parentPanel.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(Math.Abs(currAutos.X) + pointDifference.X, Math.Abs(currAutos.Y) + pointDifference.Y);
            mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;
        }

        private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                this.mouseDownPoint = Cursor.Position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your scroll on the panel works fine when you do not click on any buttons first? Or when exactly does your scroll work and when does it not. Could you elaborate?

Comment: scrolling works fine when controls (for example buttons) are created manually, in design. I can click n hold anywhere in the panel area, including on button areas. but If I create them buttons dynamically at run time. then it does not work when i click n hold on buttons area, it only works if i click n hold in the panel area.